# Prove that if a subgroup has a given property, then all subgroups have that property

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $(G, \cdot)$ be a finite abelian group. We say that $H$, a subgroup of $G$, has the property $(P)$ if $G \neq H$ and the product of all the elements in $H$ is equal to the product of all the elements in $G \setminus H$. Prove that if $G$ has a subgroup which has the property $(P)$, then all proper subgroups of $G$ have the property $(P)$.

I haven't managed to do anything meaningful yet.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The product of all elements of $H$ is actually simply the product of all elements of order $2$, and the same holds for $G\setminus H$ (try to think of why this is true).

Thus, if we list all elements of order $2$ as $x_1,\ldots,x_m,x_{m+1},\ldots x_n$, with $x_1,\ldots,x_n\in H$ and $x_{m+1},\ldots,x_n\in G\setminus H$, then $H$ has property $P$ iff $x_1\cdots x_m=x_{m+1}\cdots x_n$. But all of these have order $2$ and $G$ is abelian, so this is the same as $x_1\cdots x_n=1$, which does not depend on the given subgroup $H$.